# Which algorithm helps me offset sensor fused data?

Tags: c#, accelerometer, gyroscope, magnetometer

I have this sensor fused data coming from a GYRO-ACC-MAG-hardware sensor.

It's data (YAW-PITCH-ROLL) goes from `-180` to `+180` or `-90` to `+90`

Which algorithm helps me offset this to an arbitrary position and also have no sign change to minus?

What I mean is: `-180` to `+180` for instance leads to `0` to `359`. And I want `0` not where `0` of the sensor is but also offset to a certain position. In other words, picture a circle. Now put a zero at an arbitrary position on that circle. Now rotate that circle around it's center point. The zero rotates along, so it is now at a different position than it was before, right? That's the idea.

What I did:

`YAW + 180` leads to `0 to 359`. `Pitch + 90` leads to `0 to 179`. `Roll + 180` leads to `0 to 359`.

Comment: This isn't clear.  The "algorithm" for your example appears to be "add 180".

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I am sorry for demanding too little from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to make use of the modulo operator:

```
double YAW360 =  (YAW+180)%360;
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx

The modulo operator makes a division and returns the division *remainder*:

```
17 / 5 = 3 rest 2
```

Therefore:

```
17 % 5 = 2
```

Comment: Where does `And I want 0 not where 0 of the sensor is but also offset to a certain position.` come into play?

Comment: Also, what are you doing? How did you understand my question?

Comment: @PeakReconstructionWavelength: I don't know how to parse that sentence, so probably nowhere...

Comment: That depends on  what you add to the value *before* taking the modulo. In your case, you don't add 180 like my example, you add 360 to ensure a positibe value. Example values: `(0+360) % 360 = 0`, `(-90+180) % 360 = 270`

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Alright, picture a Circle. Now put a zero at an arbitrary position on that circle. Now rotate that circle around it's center point. The zero rotates along, so it is now at a different position than it was before, right? That's the idea.

Comment: @joe I am afraid, we are talking about different things.

Comment: I don't think so. There are two questions here: (1) make an offset to the *zero* angle, this can be solved by simply subtract an `offset` from the original sensor angle. (2) To ensure that the angle has a positive value, use the modulo operator using 360 or 180°. So please think about this or try the two steps in your program and let us see your results.

Comment: @joe I thought about it and your modulo seems like a limiter for values to stay within a certain area(here 360). That's a great idea if I understood it right. But thinking back to my education - as you write it - modulo delivers the rest. I don't really understand in how far this mathematical method acts as a limiter. Maybe you can elaborate...

Comment: And sorry - when I say *rest* I meant *remainder*